# Jekyll node_modules not found while using load_paths

Tags: javascript, jquery, jekyll

I am trying to configure jQuery in a Jekyll project. I am having issues referencing my script tags (if I include a cdn its fine).

I was reading up on some issues where github-pages may not process your node_modules. But, I am just working locally with no luck.

Would js files be loaded differently not under a `sass:` > `load_paths:`? Does it matter? (Sass files work fine but no js files are working)

_config.yml

```
sass:
  load_paths:
    - _sass
    - node_modules/
```

My footer:

```
<script src="{{'/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js' | prepend: site.baseurl}}"></script>
```

Error:

> [2019-03-27 12:44:36] ERROR `/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'
>   not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `exclude: []` to `my _config.yml` file fixed this issue should this help anyone.

Comment: Also interested in an explanation if anyone comes across this question again and has some info

Comment: I did this exact same thing but i still get the same error. Is this still working with the current version of Jekyll?

Comment: Is your file structure the same? Check your scripts?

Comment: My file structure is the same. it's actually an initial installation of jekyll for development

Answer (score 6):

Had the same issue. For me adding following to the _config.yml helped:

```
include             : [".htaccess", "node_modules"]
exclude             : ["Gemfile", "Gemfile.lock", "vendor/bundle/", "vendor/cache/", "vendor/gems/", "vendor/ruby/"]
```

It seems like just removing "node_modules" from exclude does not help, you have to explicitely add it to the includes.

Comment: include: ["node_modules"]     worked for me.